# Setting "env" on the "on" field in a GitHub Workflow

Tags: github, github-actions

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
      - 'releases/**'
```

The above is from the documents here: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#using-filters

Is it possible to include `env` in this area? And example like the following:

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
        env: // <-- this
          TOKEN: token-on-push-on-main
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main
        env: // <-- and this
          TOKEN: token-on-pull-request-on-main
```

Answer (score 1):

No, it's impossible to do it like this.

But you can add a step that will identify the trigger, by checking if `${{ github.event_name }}` is `pull_request` or `push` and based on that set env value.

One example will be:

```
env:
    TOKEN: "${{ github.event_name == 'push' && 'token-on-push-on-main' || 'token-on-pull-request-on-main' }}"
```